# Switch Case To/Between

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Is there a way in Javascript to compare one integer with another through switch case structures without using if statements?

E.g.

```
switch(integer) {
    case 1 to 10:
        break;
    case 11 to 20:
        break;
    case 21 to 30:
        break;
}
```

Comment: No. Well, you could have `switch(integer < 10) { case  true:....}` (which is comparing an integer with another through `switch`) but I guess that's not helpful.

Comment: Ah ok. I asked because it would seem a lot easier to read and code than if(integer<= 10) and so forth. I've seen the syntax somewhere before, but I forget where and what for.

Answer (score 6):

You can do some math manipulations.

```
switch(Math.ceil(integer/10)) {
    case 1: // Integer is between 1-10
        break;
    case 2: // Integer is between 11-20
        break;
    case 3: // Integer is between 21-30
        break;
}
```

Comment: That's awesome! Keeps the cases nice and simple.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way, yes. I'm pretty sure I'd use an if/else structure in my own code, but if you're keen to use a switch the following will work:

```
switch(true) {
   case integer >= 1 && integer <= 10:
      // 1-10
      break;
   case integer >= 11 && integer <= 20: 
      // 11-20
      break;
   case integer >= 21 && integer <= 30:
      // 21-30
      break;
}
```

Of course if you wanted to avoid having to code `>= && <=` on every case you could define your own `isInRange(num,min,max)` type function to return a boolean and then say:

```
switch (true) {
   case isInRange(integer,1,10):
      // 1-10
      break;
   // etc
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated in my comment, you can't do that. However, you could define an `inRange` function:

```
function inRange(x, min, max) {
    return min <= x && x <= max;
}
```

and use it together with `if - else if`. That should make it quite easy to read:

```
if(inRange(integer, 1, 10)) {

}
else if(inRange(integer, 11, 20)) {

}

//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting for "cool" syntax :P

```
if( integer in range(0, 10 ) ) {

}
else if ( integer in range( 11, 20 ) ) {



}
else if ( integer in range( 21, 30 ) ) {



}

function range( min, max ){
var o = {}, i ;
    for( i = min; i <= max; ++i ) {
    o[i] = !0;
    }
return o;
}
```

Comment: Why is `o[i] = !0` better than `o[i] = true`? For being cool? ;) Creating an object like this every time seems to be a waste, but using `in` this way is creative I have to admit (though probably not very performant).

Comment: @FelixKling yeah :D Not really meant for any real use unless you must have that sweet integer in range syntax

Comment: I give you a "virtual" +1 for creativity ;)

Comment: Uh, what an anti-pattern... `:P`