# how to use switch case(range of number) in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try to user switch (range of number)
but it seems not work?
can you help me check it where is the problem?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://goo.gl/mK5WJK)

```
case (tot>10 && tot<110):
         $total.html(tot);
         $risk.html('小');
break;

case (tot>110 && tot<310):
         $total.html(tot);
         $risk.html('大');
```

Comment: Its not possible in the way you have illustrated, check this out for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616724/jquery-using-ranges-in-switch-cases

Comment: This works in JavaScript because the language spec is such that duplicate case expression values are not a problem. In some languages, that's not OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use just as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528869/switch-case-to-between)

```
switch (true) {
    case (tot>10 && tot<110):
        $total.html(tot);
        $risk.html('小');
        break;
    case (tot>110 && tot<310):
        $total.html(tot);
        $risk.html('大');
        break;
 }
```

Comment: so it's kind of duplicated question, better mark it as duplicated rather than referencing another answer.

Comment: Sure. Do you mean suggesting that is duplicated or doing something else? I don't know how to do it.

Comment: maybe your reputation is not enough to vote close for duplicated reason.

Comment: I will keep this in mind next time. Thanks for the advice.